# convert intent filter manifest to intent filter java

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

i wrote this intent filter in android manifest and is correct but i want convert this intent filter so that`s in the android service and i remove intent filter from android manifest.

```
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
       <data android:scheme="http" />
       <data android:scheme="https" />
       <data android:host="*" />
       <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.zip" />
       <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.zip.*" />
   <intent-filter>
```

i wrote these codes in java but dose not work intent and start with default download manager:(

```
    MyReceiver mReceiver = new MyReceiver();//this is a BrodcastReciver class
    IntentFilter f = new IntentFilter();
    f.addAction("android.intent.action.VIEW");
    f.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
    f.addCategory("android.intent.category.BROWSABLE");
    f.addDataScheme("http");
    f.addDataScheme("https");
    f.addDataAuthority("*", null);
    f.addDataPath(".*\\.zip",PatternMatcher.PATTERN_SIMPLE_GLOB);
    f.addDataPath(".*\\.zip.*", PatternMatcher.PATTERN_SIMPLE_GLOB);
    Log.e("intent and brodcast", "seved");
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, f);
```

whats the problem?
please help me

tanks;)

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: i don`t know.this is strang:(

Comment: No, I mean what doesn't work? Are you getting an Exception? Is it not compiling?

Comment: no,compiled and correct run,but not work intent and started download with default download manager

Answer (score 0):

when you are using Intent filter in your java file, add **createchooser()** property into it.

At the time of launching action, add these lines:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
...

// Always use string resources for UI text.
// This says something like "Share this photo with"
String title = getResources().getString(R.string.chooser_title);
// Create intent to show the chooser dialog
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, title);

// Verify the original intent will resolve to at least one activity
if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(chooser);
}
```

By adding this code, you will be able to launch the action in whichever browser you want to use.